# How do I create a chain for data with parent child relationship using python?

Tags: python, airflow

If I have this set of input to convert,
Input:

```
Task A -> Task B
Task A -> Task C
Task B -> Task D
Task C -> Task E
```

Making use of pandas python:
`df = pd.DataFrame({"parent": ['Task A', 'Task A', 'Task B, 'Task C'], "child":["Task B", "Task C", 'Task D', 'Task E']})` as my input.

Output:

```
Task A >> (Task B, Task C) >> (Task D, Task E)
```

Function will return above result.

I will hope to achieve this output as I am using the output to provide airflow to configure the relationship of my tasks.

Comment: could you be more precise? what's the input/output format? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your Pandas example, but in Airflow you can create 1-to-1 and 1-to-many dependencies between tasks in Airflow, but you cannot create many-to-many dependencies in Airflow using the bitshift operators (`>>` and `<<`).

Those can be set using a for loop:

```py
tasks_a = [t1, t2, t3]
tasks_b = [t4, t5, t6]

for task in tasks_a:
    task >> tasks_b
```

Or using Airflow's `cross_downstream()` function:

```py
from airflow.models.baseoperator import cross_downstream

tasks_a = [t1, t2, t3]
tasks_b = [t4, t5, t6]
cross_downstream(from_tasks=tasks_a, to_tasks=tasks_b)
```

Which will create dependencies from all tasks in `tasks_a` to all tasks in `tasks_b`:

[image]